# How to get a Data Source generated details form to default to TwoWay Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I've got some classes in VS 2010 that I'm creating details forms for using the Data Sources window. Some types, like Guid, are bound to custom user controls (which have been set up with DefaultBindingProperty, etc). When I generate the form though, it sets regular control's default binding to TwoWay, where as my custom user controls are not. I get this in the XAML:

```
SelectedItemGUID="{Binding Path=client.ReportingContactGUID}"
```

whereas other controls get:

```
Text="{Binding Path=client.State, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, 
               NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
```

I don't care about the Validation error stuff, but I would like it if `Mode=TwoWay` appeared in there automatically. Is this an attribute or something I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want your `custom Dependency Properties to bind twoWay be default` which you can by passing `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag for FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions while registering your custom dependency properties.

Sample:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemGUIDProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemGUID", typeof(Guid?),
       typeof(YourUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
                         FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

This way you don't have to explicitly need to set `Mode=TwoWay` for bindings to this custom DP.

Comment: This looks like it would do what I want if I were using WPF, but I'm using Silverlight, and it doesn't like like FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions exists in Silverlight, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Yeah you not available in Silverlight as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691856/frameworkpropertymetadataoptions-in-silverlight).